# Cannot find namespace in angular

Tags: angular

Following this: => https://cesium.com/blog/2018/03/12/cesium-and-angular/

I have a global var in my typing.d.ts =>

```
declare var Cesium;
```

my tsConfig contain =>

```
"typeRoots": [
  "node_modules/@types",
  "./src/typings.d.ts"
],
```

Now, In my directive, I have the following

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, OnInit, Input, Output} from '@angular/core';
import * as CesiumLib from '../libs/cesium.lib';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appCesium]'
})
export class CesiumDirective implements OnInit {
  @Input() appCesiumOptions: CesiumLib.CesiumViewerOptions;
  @Output() appCesiumViewer: Cesium.Viewer;

  constructor(private el: ElementRef) {
    Cesium.Ion.defaultAccessToken = CesiumLib.CESIUM_ACCESS_TOKEN;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    const appCesiumViewer = new Cesium.Viewer(this.el.nativeElement, this.appCesiumOptions);
  }
}
```

the line

```
const appCesiumViewer = new Cesium.Viewer
```

work ok and without error, but the line

```
@Output() appCesiumViewer: Cesium.Viewer;
```

give me the following

> Cannot find namespace 'Cesium'.

I also try to make a structure, but I have the same error

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

export the declared module

```
export declare var Cesium;
```

Comment: thanks, but I have a question, the typing was added to the typeroot and working from within function. only those typedeclaraction where not working.

If I add the export, then nothing works unless i specifically import the typing.d.ts.
but I believe this is dodging the purpose of the typeroot

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me.

First, install package for example moment.

```
npm install moment --save
```

Then, to work around the lack of a proper export:

import * as moment from 'moment';

Note: `import * as moment from 'moment';` format is important

```
import * as aliasname from 'packagename';
```

Comment: this one too I have to do for everyfile I need the namespace right ?